# Deploying of Java project not happening in Jenkins using Maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, maven-deploy-plugin

I having a Java project and I'm trying to compile it using Maven and deploying the Jar file into Nexus.

I tried it as a Jenkins Maven job and Jenkins pipeline job, and in both the scenarios I'm getting the below issue in console output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy (default-deploy) @ myproject.test ---
[INFO] Skipping artifact deployment
```

The Jar file is created and placed in the Jenkins slave machine, but the deployment to Nexus alone is not happening. I have checked for **maven.skip.deploy** parameter in pom.xml and that has been set as false. Not getting sure like what could be the reason for this error, can someone provide your inputs regarding the issue ? thanks !

Comment: You could run maven with `-X` parameter. Maybe you'll get more information why the step is skipped.

Comment: I have tried that already and I'm getting this - org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ChecksumFailureException: Checksum validation failed, no checksums available

Comment: Please show the full log output ?

Comment: Resolution to the problem would greatly be appreciated.